# SQL Server - Select Distinct of two columns, where the distinct column selected has a maximum value based on two other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, multiple-columns

I have 2 tables - TC and T, with columns specified below. TC maps to T on column T_ID.

```
TC
----
T_ID,
TC_ID

T
-----
T_ID,
V_ID, 
Datetime,
Count
```

My current result set is:

```
V_ID TC_ID  Datetime     Count   
----|-----|------------|--------|
2   | 1   | 2013-09-26 | 450600 |
2   | 1   | 2013-12-09 | 14700  |  
2   | 1   | 2014-01-22 | 15000  |
2   | 1   | 2014-01-22 | 15000  |
2   | 1   | 2014-01-22 | 7500   |
4   | 1   | 2014-01-22 | 1000   |
4   | 1   | 2013-12-05 | 0      |
4   | 2   | 2013-12-05 | 0      |
```

Using the following query:

```
select T.V_ID, 
    TC.TC_ID, 
    T.Datetime,
    T.Count 
    from T 
    inner join TC 
    on TC.T_ID = T.T_ID
```

Result set I want:

```
V_ID TC_ID  Datetime     Count   
----|-----|------------|--------|  
2   | 1   | 2014-01-22 | 15000  |
4   | 1   | 2014-01-22 | 1000   |
4   | 2   | 2013-12-05 | 0      |
```

I want to write a query to select each distinct `V_ID + TC_ID` combination, but only with the maximum datetime, and for that datetime the maximum count. E.g. for the distinct combination of `V_ID = 2` and `TC_ID = 1`, `'2014-01-22'` is the maximum datetime, and for that datetime, `15000` is the maximum count, so select this record for the new table. Any ideas? I don't know if this is too ambitious for a query and I should just handle the result set in code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select v_id, tc_id, datetime, count
from (select T.V_ID, TC.TC_ID, T.Datetime, T.Count,
             row_number() over (partition by t.V_ID, tc.tc_id
                                order by datetime desc, count desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t join
           tc
           on tc.t_id = t._id
     ) tt
where seqnum = 1;
```

The only issue is that some rows have the same maximum `datetime` value.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no way to determine which is really the maximum -- unless the `datetime` really has a time component or another column specifies the ordering within a day.

Comment: order by datetime desc,count desc *

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to solve this using CTEs. First, extracting the data from your query. Second, get the maxdates. Third, get the highest count for each maxdate.:

```
;WITH Dataset AS 
(
    select T.V_ID, 
    TC.TC_ID, 
    T.[Datetime],
    T.[Count] 
    from T 
    inner join TC 
    on TC.T_ID = T._ID
),
MaxDates AS 
(
    SELECT V_ID, TC_ID, MAX(t.[Datetime]) AS MaxDate
    FROM Dataset t
    GROUP BY t.V_ID, t.TC_ID
)
SELECT t.V_ID, t.TC_ID, t.[Datetime], MAX(t.[Count]) AS [Count]
FROM Dataset t
INNER JOIN MaxDates m ON t.V_ID = m.V_ID AND t.TC_ID = m.TC_ID AND m.MaxDate = t.[Datetime]
GROUP BY t.V_ID, t.TC_ID, t.[Datetime]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep it simple:
You need to group by T.V_ID,TC.TC_ID,
with selecting the max of date and then to get the maximum count, you must use a sub query as follows,

```
select T.V_ID, 
    TC.TC_ID, 
    max(T.Datetime) as Date_Time,
    (select max(Count) from T as tb where v_ID = T.v_ID and DateTime = max(T.DateTime)) as Count
    from T 
    inner join TC 
    on TC.T_ID = T._ID
group by T.V_ID,TC.TC_ID,
```

Comment: This does not work as it is - T.DateTime is not in a group by clause or an aggregate function so the query errors.

Comment: @spitfire sorry i forgot to use the max with T.DateTime, so please check it now after i edited.